# Use title based slugs and archive IDs at the same time

Tags: wordpress

A wordpress site I am working on was previously windows hosted and could not use htaccess to hide the index.php.  All 200 or so news items are indexed by the search engines like

sitename.com/index.php/archives/5574‎

The site is now being moved to Linux, and the news items will now be like

sitename.com/big-story-of-the-week

If I change the permalink structure as proposed, is there any way I can get the site to still route the old index.php/archive links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file, you can add the following code using your sites URL structure:

Redirect 301 index.php/archives/5574‎ http://sitename.com/big-story-of-the-week

This would have to be done for each page.

More info here: http://wp-mix.com/redirect-urls-htaccess/

(Be sure to backup your .htaccess prior to making changes)